# Anaconda3 Docker: /bin/bash: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, debian, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/) for anaconda3. On dockerhub, it gives an example about running a jupyter notebook:

```
 docker run -i --rm -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"
```

But it quits with the message

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Also, I'm not able to use `bash`, `apt-get` and various other command line tools. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuum recently decided to switch their base image from debian to alpine linux (see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/120)). Therefore, you need to replace some command line tools:

- `bash` -> `sh`
- `apt-get` -> `apk`

You can start a jupyter notebook with docker anaconda3 like this:

```
docker run -i --rm -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/sh -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='0.0.0.0' --port=8888 --no-browser"
```

…and visit http://localhost:8888/